# AWS SDK C++ error in CMakeLists.txt target_link_library

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, cmake

I have been following [text](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-cpp/v1/developer-guide/setup-windows.html) in window, and trying to do hello_s3 project for the next step shown in document.
But when I try cmake I kept getting this error :
[CMake Error at /CMakeLists.txt:37 (target_link_libraries)]
[imported library can only be used with the interface keyword of target_link_libraries]

```
# Set the minimum required version of CMake for this project.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

# Set the AWS service components used by this project.
set(SERVICE_COMPONENTS s3)

# Set this project's name.
project("test")

# Set the C++ standard to use to build this target.
# At least C++ 11 is required for the AWS SDK for C++.
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

# Use the MSVC variable to determine if this is a Windows build.
set(WINDOWS_BUILD ${MSVC})

if (WINDOWS_BUILD) # Set the location where CMake can find the installed libraries for the AWS SDK.
    string(REPLACE ";" "/aws-cpp-sdk-all;" SYSTEM_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH}/aws-cpp-sdk-all")
    list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${SYSTEM_MODULE_PATH})
endif ()

# Find the AWS SDK for C++ package.
find_package(AWSSDK REQUIRED COMPONENTS s3)

if (WINDOWS_BUILD)
    # Copy relevant AWS SDK for C++ libraries into the current binary directory for running and debugging.

    # set(BIN_SUB_DIR "/Debug") # if you are building from the command line you may need to uncomment this
    # and set the proper subdirectory to the executables' location.

    AWSSDK_CPY_DYN_LIBS(SERVICE_COMPONENTS "" ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}${BIN_SUB_DIR})
endif ()

add_executable(${test}
        hello_s3.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${test}
        ${AWSSDK_LINK_LIBRARIES})
```

where should I fix?

I tried changing last line to

```
target_link_libraries(${test}
        PRIVATE AWSSDK::aws-cpp-sdk-core
        PRIVATE AWSSDK::aws-cpp-sdk-s3)
```

but still doesn't work, and I use VS2022

Comment: The error message is about `target_link_libraries` where the very **first argument** is the IMPORTED target. The code you show doesn't fit for the error message: it has (regular) executable target as the first argument. Also, total number of lines in the shown code is 32, but the error message is about line 37. You need to find `CMakeLists.txt` which is **actually referenced** in the error message.

Comment: @Tsyvarev 
Thanks, I found out I was using 'CMakeList.txt' at wrong location. But still it gives me same error at 'target_link_libraries'

Comment: Please, [edit] your question post and update the code and/or error message, so they would fit to one another. In the current form the error message doesn't correspond to the code.

Comment: BTW, your code uses `test` **variable**, but where this variable is **defined**? The call `project("test")` doesn't define `test` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should use PRIVATE only once.

```
target_link_libraries(${test}
    PRIVATE 
    AWSSDK::aws-cpp-sdk-core
    AWSSDK::aws-cpp-sdk-s3)
```

Comment: CMake allows to specify `PRIVATE` keyword as many times as you want. Replacing them with a single `PRIVATE` keyword may make the code shorter, but it wouldn't eliminate any error.